# method_descriptor object has no attribute 'now' - while returning in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

while running the below snippet the error is thrown on datetime.time.now()
Error msg : method_descriptor object has no attribute 'now'

```
 from datetime import datetime
     def samplefun(file_path, max_width=0, width=0, height=0):
     file_dir = _get_file_dir(file_path)
     file_name = _get_file_name(file_path)
       
     return f"{file_dir}/thumbnails/{max_width}/pro_pic{datetime.time.now()}.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `time` namespace:

`datetime.now()`

EDIT:

If you need to remove certain parts of the timestamp, use `replace`:

`datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)`

Comment: I want only the time to be displayed not entire thing for example if use datetime.now()

it will be saved as  2021-04-20 07:16:51.992148.jpg which call issue in the file name , hence i need only timestamp and date

Comment: That is just the timestamp and date. Can you be more specific with the format you need?

Comment: i need "pro_pic2021-04-20 07:16:51.jpg" like this

Comment: Then you can use the `replace` method of `datetime`:
`datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)`

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for this. Hope this helps.

Comment: One more query what if ,I need it seconds only like pro_pic278368263827..jpg"

Comment: what if need it only  in seconds "pro_pic28632748043.jpg" like this